# Android WebView Destroy

Tags: java, android

Opa pessoal estou com um certo problema quando eu executo um destroy em uma webview.

```
    wb.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wb.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    wb.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

detalhe isso só ocorre quando eu seto o JavaScriptEnable.

```
            mWebContainer.removeView(wb);
            wb.clearHistory();
            wb.stopLoading();
            wb.clearView();
            wb.clearCache(true);
            wb.destroyDrawingCache();
            wb.setWebChromeClient(null);
            wb.setWebViewClient(null);
            wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
            wb.removeAllViews();
            wb.destroy();
```

Já tentei quase tudo para dar o destroy sem que o erro acontecesse

> 04-02 13:34:14.893: E/webview(24263): java.lang.Throwable: Error: WebView.destroy() called while still attached!
>   04-02 13:34:14.893: E/webview(24263):   at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.destroy(WebViewClassic.java:2188)
>   04-02 13:34:14.893: E/webview(24263):   at android.webkit.WebView.destroy(WebView.java:647)
>   04-02 13:34:14.893: E/webview(24263):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4421)
>   04-02 13:34:14.893: E/webview(24263):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17903)
>   04-02 13:34:14.893: E/webview(24263):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>   04-02 13:34:14.893: E/webview(24263):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   04-02 13:34:14.893: E/webview(24263):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
>   04-02 13:34:14.893: E/webview(24263):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
>   04-02 13:34:14.893: E/webview(24263):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   04-02 13:34:14.893: E/webview(24263):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>   04-02 13:34:14.893: E/webview(24263):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
>   04-02 13:34:14.893: E/webview(24263):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
>   04-02 13:34:14.893: E/webview(24263):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.webkit.ZoomManager.onSizeChanged(ZoomManager.java:955)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.onSizeChanged(WebViewClassic.java:5689)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.webkit.WebView.onSizeChanged(WebView.java:2157)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.view.View.sizeChange(View.java:14582)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.view.View.setFrame(View.java:14557)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.webkit.WebView.access$701(WebView.java:243)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.webkit.WebView$PrivateAccess.super_setFrame(WebView.java:1788)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.setFrame(WebViewClassic.java:5665)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.webkit.WebView.setFrame(WebView.java:2151)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14468)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:452)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:452)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1984)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1738)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1008)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5508)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
>   04-02 13:34:15.294: E/AndroidRuntime(24263):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa remover o WebView da sua view.
Exemplo:

```
webViewPlaceholder.removeView(myWebView);
myWebView.removeAllViews();
myWebView.destroy();
```

[SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995270/error-webview-destroy-called-while-still-attached)

---

Seguem um exemplo simples:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/root" >

    <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/webView" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="Remove" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:onClick="onClickButton"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

```java
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView wb;
    private LinearLayout ll;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        this.wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        this.wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        this.wb.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        this.wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        this.wb.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        this.wb.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

        this.ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.root);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        this.wb.loadUrl("http://www.google.com.br");
    }

    public void onClickButton(View view) {
        //deatach the view
        ll.removeView(wb);
        wb.clearHistory();
        wb.stopLoading();
        wb.clearView();
        wb.clearCache(true);
        wb.destroyDrawingCache();
        wb.setWebChromeClient(null);
        wb.setWebViewClient(null);
        wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        wb.removeAllViews();
        wb.destroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Bom eu já tentei removendo ele da view, porem o mesmo erro persiste.

Comment: Tentou desabilitar o javascript antes de remover o webview?

Comment: Sim, wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
apesar de não ser muito recomendado fazer isso eu fiz e o erro persiste.

Comment: Onde você chama o wb.destroy()? Dentro de qual método?

Comment: Dentro de um click em um botão

Comment: Qual versão do Android você esta utilizando? Pode postar o xml e a classe?

Comment: Poxa Otto não sei porque mas minha webView estava dentro de um linear que estava dentro de um relative então tirei o linear deixei so o relative e deu certo mas seu exemplo ajudou muito VLWZÂO !!!